# Solana JSON RPC API getBalance method always returns 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solana-web3js

I am trying to get the SOL balance from a phantom wallet. The wallet has > 0 SOL in it, so I know that something is wrong when I make the call. Here is my code:

```
(async () => {
            const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(
                solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
                'confirmed',
            );

            if (phantom && phantom.publicKey !== null) {
                const balance = await connection.getBalance(phantom.publicKey)
                console.log(balance);
            }
})();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that phantom.publicKey is actually your public key?

Comment: @benmotyka yep, it's an object (not the base 58 string) which I'm passing to getBalance()

Comment: Can you please provide me with output of:

balance / solanaWeb3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL

Comment: @benmotyka the output is 0

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks like it might be with the assignment to phantom.publicKey itself and not your code. Replacing phantom.public key with a defined public key below works.

```
const solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');

const public_key=new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("your Solana public address with non-0 balance");

(async () => {
            const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(
                solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
                'confirmed',
            );

            if (public_key !== null) {
                const balance = await connection.getBalance(public_key);
                console.log(balance)
            }
})();
```

Comment: Hmm it's still returning 0. I instantiated `PublicKey` with the base58 string key for the Phantom wallet and passed it to `getBalance`

Comment: do you have the full code? Everything i'm seeing above is working.